# How to use Wifi re-installation code?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-ace

I've a Samsung Galaxy Ace but my Wifi is always not in range.

[Google Helps](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Mobile/thread?tid=65705f7d0cae93ba&hl=en) state:

> Use WiFi driver re-installation Code `*#*#526#*#*`...Reinstall the
>   firmware for Wifi. Try it on other Routers as well  this is a common
>   problem with Androids. as i see (seen in lot of forums people
>   discussing Wifi problem of Androids) My cousin bought the same Handset
>   and he is having same problem. If it doesn't help show it to your
>   vendor from where you have brought it

How do I use the WiFi driver re-installation Code `*#*#526#*#*` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on Galaxy Ace but I dialed *#526# and not *#*#526#*#*. I don't know if it's the same thing. Also try with removing and renewing the Wi-Fi connection on your phone.

Answer (score 2):

These are called dialer codes, so naturally try typing it into your Dialer as if it were a phone number.  I just did it on my Vibrant and got this:

```
WlanTest Engineering Mode
Status...
Unloading Normal Driver and Loading Mfg Driver

Driver loading successful
```

Comment: @Pacerier I know some other things like touchscreen drivers might have similar codes, but in general you don't want to mess with drivers.  Most of your installs will be apps, which certainly aren't done through dialer codes :P

Comment: Btw my Wifi still doesn't seem to be in range evne after installing the driver and restarting the device. Do you have any idea what may be causing the problem?

Comment: @Pacerier Sorry, no.  Have you tried it with multiple Wi-Fi networks?